# How to pass multiple parameter in a GET request inside a API symfony2?

Tags: api, symfony, parameters, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I am using a FOSRestBundle and I am pretty new in Symfony.

I've been following some exemples I've seen but I can't add more than one parameter in the request.

For example

```
/**
     *  
     * @param  string $id Identifier
     * @return [type]     [description]
     *
     * @ApiDoc()
     */
    public function getProductsAction($id)
    {
        return myfunction($id);
    }
```

works fine, but if I want to do a variation like this:

```
 /**
     *  
     * @param  string $id Identifier
     * @return [type]     [description]
     *
     * @ApiDoc()
     */
    public function getProductsAction($id, $month)
    {
        return myfunction($id, $month);
    }
```

It doesn't work.  It identifies only the $id

There is any limitation I am not aware? or some extra configuration beyond the simple modification I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
/**
 *  
 * @param  string $id Identifier
 * @return [type]     [description]
 *
 * @ApiDoc()
 */
public function getProductsAction($id)
{
    return myfunction($id);
}
```

it's equivalent to

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;

/**
 * @Get("/products/{id}")
 * @param  string $id Identifier
 * @return [type]     [description]
 *
 * @ApiDoc()
 */
public function getProductsAction($id)
{
    return myfunction($id);
}
```

Symfony maps automatically the route and parameter.

But when you write

```
/**
 *  
 * @param  string $id Identifier
 * @return [type]     [description]
 *
 * @ApiDoc()
 */
public function getProductsAction($id, $month)
{
    return myfunction($id, $month);
}
```

Symfoy doesn't know what to do with your `$month` parameter, you need to tell it

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;

/**
 * @Get("/products/{id}/{month}")
 * @param  string $id Identifier
 * @return [type]     [description]
 *
 * @ApiDoc()
 */
public function getProductsAction($id, $month)
{
    return myfunction($id, $month);
}
```

Comment: The @get is an annotation from which symfony component?
I am getting a non imported use statement.

Comment: @MatheusOliveira it's the annotation from FOSRestBundle, i've included it in the answer :)